# Can I resize static tableview according to screen size using storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I have a static `UITableView` with 7 cells of different heights. They are built for iphone 5 screen. Now, if the device is Iphone 4, how do I resize these cells keeping the same proportion of the heights related to the Iphone 5 screen and also resize the subviews proportionally according to `UITableViewCell` height?

I can think of a solution to override `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, ask for the screen size and changing the heights accordingly. But that will be a little pain and a manual job, I'm looking for something more automatic, if possible, using storyboards.

Comment: Do you actually need to resize the cells? `UITableViews` and `UIScrollViews` in general play nicely with different screen sizes by allowing scrolling. Why not just leave the cell heights and allow the user to scroll up and down on smaller screens?

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestion, but my design has a sliding up menu on the bottom of the screen, besides, the static content should all fit the screen. I just used a tableview because it was easier to layout this way. But I really need the content to be all there, no scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of this is static you should be able to use Storyboard's Auto Layout feature... Have you tried that?

This would be a good place to start:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1